# SVG Polyline drawing of limits

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, svg

Hey guys im trying to use a ie feature or bug, but it works fine for my solution.

In IE if i have a smaller svg with a larger polyline, the polyline shows through the svg edges.

The same code not work on other browsers and i need to understand why works only on IE.

Has any css or js that i can change to set all browsers to make results equal ie ?

Here is the code, run on IE and run on other browsers, you only view the line in ie and is what i need.

```css
svg
{
    border: solid 1px red;  margin: 40px 40px 20px 20px;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <style> svg { border: solid 1px red; margin: 40px 40px 20px 20px; } </style> <body> <svg height="20" width="50"> <polyline points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180 200,-10" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" /> </svg> </body> </html>
```

See that only IE draws the line over the edges.

[image: See the image]

Comment: See the code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
 svg
    {
     border: solid 1px red;  margin: 40px 40px 20px 20px;    
        }
</style>
<body>

<svg height="20" width="50">
  <polyline points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180 200,-10" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Setting a style `overflow: visible;` for the svg element should help.

For details on the rules, see the SVG [overflow](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/render.html#OverflowAndClipProperties) spec. A `overflow: hidden;` is set by a conforming browser stylesheet if a `<svg>` element is not the root of a stand-alone document.

Note that you will still have to deal with the overflow rules of all parent elements.